Issues with MySQL connection in my C++ (on clion) project using MySQL Connector C++
I'm working on a C++ project for managing users in a library, and I'm using MySQL Connector C++ to interact with a MySQL database. I am encountering a few issues in my code that I can't seem to resolve.

Error "Cannot resolve symbol 'con'":

In several functions in my code, I get this error, even though I believe I have correctly declared and initialized my con variable (database connection) in the main() function. My goal is to use this variable in all the functions that require a database connection.
I also get the error

Error "Cannot resolve symbol 'sql'":

when trying to use types like sql::Connection, sql::PreparedStatement, etc. However, I have included the necessary libraries in the code and properly configured the header and library file paths.
If anyone has an idea of what might be causing these issues or suggestions on how to resolve them, I would really appreciate your help! these are the first lines of my code
           #include <iostream>
           #include <mysql_driver.h>
           #include <mysql_connection.h>
           #include <regex>


           void afficherMenu();
           void inscription(sql::Connection *con);
           void modifierUtilisateur(sql::Connection *con);
           void supprimerUtilisateur(sql::Connection *con);
           void gererRoles(sql::Connection *con);

           bool emailValide(const std::string &email) {
           const std::regex pattern(R"((\w+)(\.{0,1}) 
           (\w*)@(\w+)\. 
           (\w+))");
           return std::regex_match(email, pattern);
           }

           int main() {
           try {
                // Connexion à la base de données
           cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
           project(gestionUtilisateurs)

           set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

           # Ajouter les chemins d'inclusion pour MySQL Connector 
           C++
           include_directories(
           "C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0- 
           winx64/mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0-winx64/include"
           "C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0- 
           winx64/mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0-winx64/lib64/vs14"
           )

           # Spécifier les fichiers sources
           add_executable(gestionUtilisateurs.cpp)

           # Ajouter le chemin vers les bibliothèques
           link_directories(
           include_directories(
           "C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0- 
           winx64/mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0-winx64/include"
           )

           )

           # Lier les bibliothèques nécessaires
           target_link_libraries(gestionUtilisateurs
           mysqlcppconn
           ws2_32
           winmm
           )

this is CMakeList.txt

Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please take the tour
and read how to ask, an On Topic question,
then look at the Question Check list,
the perfect question and
how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

Basically, if we cannot see some code, does not have to be the real code, but it does have to be a working example, or rather not working example, we can only make guesses as to what maybe wrong.

#include 
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include 
void afficherMenu();
void inscription(sql::Connection *con);
void modifierUtilisateur(sql::Connection *con);
void supprimerUtilisateur(sql::Connection *con);
void gererRoles(sql::Connection *con);
thiese arethe first lines of my code

Please add code to the question, we cannot read code in a comment. Use the edit link under the question

Where did you get these header names from? The MySQL-Connector/C++ documentation uses #include <mysqlx/...>.

thank u , but my compiler still Cannot find directory 'mysqlx' in search paths and also it connot resolve symbol mysqlx and session

Edit your question with your CMakeLists.txt and the version + location of your  Mysql Connector installation

What compiler, development enviornment do you use? (e.g. CMake, or MSVC or what?) And if you did, did you use a package manager to "install" mysqlx? If you use CMake I would at least expect something like find_package(mysqlx CONFIG)

yes i use CMake

Are you using the Microsoft Compiler msvc in CLion? Remember that the mysql connector downloads only work with msvc and will not work with MinGW.

In the documentation it says: Connector/C++ now can be compiled using MinGW on Windows.
Thanks to Eric Beuque for the contribution. Note that
this enables building on MinGW but does not make MinGW an
officially supported platform for Connector/C++. (Bug
#31636723, Bug #100248) However this means you need to build it yourself using the source code and CMake.
